# Sharepoint Designer 2010 vs. 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Sharepoint designer 2013 does not  support Design view in edit mode. Microsoft says  you can use Visual Studio to edit pages.  Does Visual Studio allow you to use Design View?

Answer (score 0):

No. Visual Studio does not have design view for SharePoint master pages.

With SharePoint 2013 you can convert HTML to masterpage using design manager and nowadays latest browsers have evolved as designer tools.

Please refer this blog for further reference

http://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/sharepoint-2013-design-manager-convert-html-to-master-page/

-Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Only **Visual Webparts** in Visual Studio have the design view !